# Dragging editor resize bar makes bar "jump up" above mouse

Tags: bug, editor

When I click and drag the grip at the bottom of the code editor, resizing works but the location of the mouse doesn't track the location of the grip.  Instead, the box initially gets smaller, while the mouse stays at the original location.  The element has the `.grippie` class.

[image: Animation of the bug]

Comment: The box sizing is pretty horrible, yeah. I wrote a userstyle to just set it to a nice round number of lines so I'd never have to consider resizing it again.